# Passing multiple parameters to onClick() function with laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am currently adding functionality to an existing Laravel application. This question is probably too trivial for SO, but I'd really appreciate a quick answer, as I haven't found it myself after googling and trying different options myself:

I want to call this JS function:
`function editItem(id, field_editable) {`

The way I am trying to call this is:
`<a ... onClick="editItem({{$item["id"]}}, {{$item["status"] == "init"}})">Edit</a>`
But this doesn't work. It used to work when only one parameter (id) was passed and requested.

Comment: What's the error in the console if you click the link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use this:

```
<a ... onClick="editItem({{$item["id"]}}, @if($item['status'] == 'init') '{{$item["status"]}}' @else "other value" @endif)">Edit</a>
```

You can also set in javascript a default value.

```
<script>
function editItem(id, status) {
    if(status == undefined) {
        status = 'my value';
    }
}
</script>

<a ... onClick="editItem({{$item["id"]}}, '{{$item["status"]}}')">Edit</a>
```

You need to set the `status` between `''`. Only if this is a string, otherwise it parses the wrong code.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the second solution and to check for the 'init' state in the script itself

Comment: You just save my weekend! I will never imagine that the second parameter need ' '

Comment: @DanielBeltrami yes, that's needed because it's a string